# How to Interact between my python script and my Django view (import, request)?

Tags: python, django, request, view, external

I explain my problem as better as I can:

I have a program written in 3 modules. I want to save some data from a site (Now I'm using a local host to make tests) to some variables and show some variables' value in the index page in this way:

```
1.- [Script: Text_Variable] <-- [localhost: ask_for_text]
  2.- [Script: Menu_Options] --> [localhost: show_menu]
  3.- [Script: Option_Variable] <-- [localhost: user_option]
4.- [Script: Response_Variable] --> [localhost: show_response]
```

Depending the value of "Text_Variable", the program do: 1 --> 4 or 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 
I could import from the script in "views.py" without problems functions and variables which made the process 1 --> 4 work properly but I have a problem with the function "Menu_Options" :
I use "POST" method for getting the data from the page, so I need to pass the argument "request" to my function in "views.py" but I call this function from the script, so I need to import that "request" in the module. I tried with these:

```
import newproject.views
import django
from django.http import request
```

**script_module.py:**

```
...
Pregunta = 'question?'
Opciones = [op1, op2...]

opc = boletin.views.Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta, Opciones)
...
```

**views.py:**

```
...
def Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta, Opciones):
    request.session['ops'] = Opciones
    request.session['preg'] = Pregunta
    Menu_Opc(request)

    opcion = request.session['op']
    return opcion
...

...
def Menu_Opc(request):
    Opciones = request.session['ops']
    Pregunta = request.session['preg']
    form = OpcionesForm(request.POST or None)
    form.Campo_Opciones.widget.choices = Opciones
    context = {
        'pregunta': Pregunta,
        'form': form,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        opcion = form.instance.ops.value() + 1
        request.session['op'] = opcion
    return render(request, "inicio.html", context)
...
```

but I had this error: **"Menu_Opciones() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Opciones'"**

Here is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.9.8
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'boletin',
 'proyectoapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\ATI\Desktop\probardjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\ATI\Desktop\probardjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\ATI\Desktop\probardjango\src\boletin\views.py" in inicio
  42.         salida = main(pregunta)

File "C:\Users\ATI\Proyecto\ESI\Main.py" in main
  52.             Respuesta = construir_respuesta(pregunta_lista, 'Profesores', CSin, TMaxCoin)

File "C:\Users\ATI\Proyecto\ESI\Entrada_Salida.py" in construir_respuesta
  127.             opc = boletin.views.Menu_Opciones(Pregunta, Opciones)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: Menu_Opciones() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Opciones'
```

Am I doing something wrong this way or there are a better way to do this?
Please, consider I'm new in this language.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I fixed one problem! I tell you how:

First I added my python modules' path to setting.py, then I decided to copy all scripts modules and paste inside my django project but forgot to change the path... Then, everytime I edited my module, I really edited the wrong file... that's why the traceback seems to have no sense.

But now I'm getting a new error:

**"'module' object has no attribute 'session'"**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.9.8
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'boletin',
 'proyectoapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\ATI\Desktop\probardjango\lib\site-    packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response =     self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\ATI\Desktop\probardjango\lib\site-    packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request,     *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\ATI\Desktop\probardjango\src\boletin\views.py" in inicio
  42.         salida = main(pregunta)

File "C:\Users\ATI\Desktop\probardjango\src\boletin\Main.py" in main
  52.             Respuesta = construir_respuesta(pregunta_lista,     'Profesores', CSin, TMaxCoin)

File "C:\Users\ATI\Desktop\probardjango\src\boletin\Entrada_Salida.py" in     construir_respuesta
  127.             opc = boletin.views.Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta,     Opciones)

File "C:\Users\ATI\Desktop\probardjango\src\boletin\views.py" in     Menu_Opciones
  137.     request.session['ops'] = Opciones

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'session'
```

if I change the import code in this way:

```
from django.http import request
```

to:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
request = HttpRequest()
```

I have this other error:

**"'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'session'"**

and the traceback is exactly equal but that error.

Is not "request" and object of "HttpRequest"?
Is not "HttpRequest" inside "django.http"?
Has not an object of "HttpRequest" an attribute 'session'?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you passing the data through POST, then all your data is inside request.POST, isn't it?

Comment: 1.- [Script: Text_Variable] <-- [localhost: ask_for_text] <--- Here data is in request.POST but the problem is here: 2.- [Script: Menu_Options] --> [localhost: show_menu] <--- Data are in variables: "Pregunta" and "Opciones" which i need to pass as parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I realised that I forgot to pass the "request" parameter when I call my script main funcion. That's why my external script "didn't know" what "request" was.

Answer (score 0):

From stacktrace, it looks like you have error in file "C:\Users\ATI\Proyecto\ESI\Entrada_Salida.py" at line number 127. There you are not passing 'request' argument while calling `Menu_Opciones` function

Comment: The line number 127 in Entrada_Salida.py is this: opc = boletin.views.Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta, Opciones)

Comment: traceback shows `opc = boletin.views.Menu_Opciones(Pregunta, Opciones)` . If it is `opc = boletin.views.Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta, Opciones)` try again and share new traceback if error happens

Comment: you're rigth! I though the problem was I didn't save the changes, but now I really do twice, and get the same error and traceback! This is stranger than I though! :\

Comment: Hello @Rohanil, I solved that mistery but I have another error, have a look please