# How can I pass the parameter "request" from a script to a view's function?

Tags: python, django, view, parameters, request

I have a script which pretend to create a form in my site and receive the response, let's call it script.py.
This script needs to call a function in views.py:

```
opc = newproject.views.Menu_Options(request, ask, Options)
```

This function needs to use request.POST, so needs to receive "request" as parameter.
The problem is:
Script.py doesn't know what is "request". I imported this:

```
import newproject.views
import django
from django.http import request
```

I ran the project but simply ignored the parameter "request" and gave me an error in this line:

```
opc = newproject.views.Menu_Options(ask, Options)


Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: Menu_Opctions() missing 1 required positional argument:     'Options'
```

Did I import a "wrong request"?
Is there any other way in views.py to import in a function the object "request" without passing it as parameter?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Not enough information. What for example is this script py? Show at least a a part of this view. in other words this is not an MVCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I realised that I forgot to pass the "request" parameter when I call my script main funcion. That's why my external script "didn't know" what "request" was.

Answer (score 3):

Importing `from django.http import request` simply imports the module [`django.http.request`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py), it won't magically pass `request` when you call the `Menu_Options` method.

You could construct a fake request object as follows:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

fake_request = HttpRequest()
fake_request.method = 'post'
fake_request.POST['foo'] = bar

# call the view with your fake request
opc = newproject.views.Menu_Options(fake_request, ask, Options)
```

However, this is very hacky. Your script should not have to create a fake request object. There is probably some common functionality in the `Menu_Options` view that you should factor out into a separate method. Then your view and script can both call the new method, but the script won't have to create a fake request object.

Comment: First thing: Thanks for the answer and this very hacky method, which i will try in case I don't find another solution :)  Second thing: @e4c5 is rigth, I did't give you enough information. All the information is here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802294/how-to-interact-between-my-python-script-and-my-django-view-import-request?noredirect=1#comment64978265_38802294[/link] I decided to make a more simple question because I didn't get a solution yet and though I needed to simplificate the problem and the question. Now seems I make it too short, I'm sorry.

Comment: I can't really help with your other question specifically. If you are writing your script to test your code, then you should have a look at the [testing tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial05/). You might find the test client useful instead of writing your own scripts that fake requests.

Comment: I tested my script and it works, I'm really using django for make it work in a  site (Now I'm using a local host as a site) Thanks for showing me to using tests in django anyway :) That's interesting

Comment: I'm sad to tell you that hacky method didn't work :( I had exactly the same error at the same line. This time "fake_request" was ignored. Can anything explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: My code might not work, but it shouldn't give you the same error as before. It's calling `Menu_Options(fake_request, ask, Options)` so it shouldn't complain about a missing argument. I don't have any other suggestions, hope you manage to get your script working.

Comment: thanks anyway @Alasdair!